# "Go to implementation" is not working in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I spent one day to fix this but with no success. As I press `ctrl` + `F12`, but it does not do anything. Pressing `F12` goes to definition, but   `ctrl` + `F12` does not do the job I want. Even choosing "Go to implementation" from menu bar fails. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Is the implementation in the same source file? If not, is the source file in the same directory?

Comment: @paddy I tried for the case that implementation is in the same directory. For the case that the implementation file was somewhere else, I added its path in c_p_p_properties.json